# Unable to do ajax refresh from a composite component

Tags: jsf-2

Here is my composite component:

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="attr1" />
    <composite:clientBehavior name="xyz" event="valueChange" targets="chkbox" />
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
    <h:panelGrid>
    <h:panelGroup>
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="chkbox"
                value="#{cc.attrs.attr1}">
            </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGrid>
</composite:implementation>
```

And my page:

```
<h:form id="myForm">
  <cc:myComp attr1="#{myBean.someAttr}">
    <f:ajax render="myform:grid1" event="xyz" listener="{myBean.listenerMethod}"/>
  </cc:myComp>

  <h:panelGrid id="grid1">
      <h:panelGroup>
         <h:inputTextarea id="rationale" rows="4" cols="70"
                value="#{myBean.rationale}" />
      </h:panelGroup>
  </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

I'm getting below error:

> `<f:ajax>` contains an unknown id 'myForm:grid1' - cannot locate it in the context of the component chkbox

If I remove `render="myform:grid1"` from my code then ajax call is working fine. Basically from my composite component I'm not able to refer another OUTSIDE component. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<f:ajax render="myform:grid1">
```

Any client ID which does not start with the `NamingContainer` separator character, which is in your case `:`, is relative to the closest `NamingContainer` parent. The closest `NamingContainer` parent is in your particular case the composite component itself. So, this construct is basically looking for a component with the full client ID `myform:XXX:myform:grid1` relative to the composite component, where `XXX` is the autogenerated ID of the composite component. However, there's no such component with this full client ID.

Assuming that the full client ID of the panel grid is indeed `myform:grid1` (i.e. when you open the page in browser, rightclick and *View Source*, you're indeed seeing `<table id="myform:grid1">`), then you should make it an absolute client ID instead by prefixing it with the `NamingContainer` separator character:

```
<f:ajax render=":myform:grid1">
```

#### See also:

- [How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-reference-components-in-jsf-ajax-cannot-find-component-with-identifier/8644762#8644762)

Comment: Working like any thing. Description what ever u provided in the given link helped me a lot. YOU are my master.